# QtCreator: Issues not displayed in Issue panel any more

Tags: qt, cmake, ide, qt-creator

I don't know what I did to break my QtCreator but "suddenly" all my compiler issues (warnings/errors) are not displayed in the issues-panel any more but only in the "Compile output" panel (where I can't use them to jump to the erroneous code just by clicking).

In the "Issues" panel only the compile target (e.g. an object file) is being displayed like this:

```
[path/to/makefile:89: path/to/object/file.cpp.o] Error 1
```

I'm using Creator together with **CMake** (with Makefiles) and **GCC**. The compiler output itself seems not to be the problem (another tool which outputs `<file>:<linenr>: <description>` shows the same result).

What are the requirements for Creator to correctly parse and display issues printed by the compiler (or any other tool)? How can I investigate what's going on?

I'm using QtCreator 4.6.2 on Fedora 27 (and I tried 4.8.0-beta1 as well with the same result)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with Creator 4.8.0 and 4.8.1 with CMAKE versions 3.13.3, 3.7.2, and 3.5.1 (the latter doesn't support server mode I think). It works in Creator 4.3.1 with the same versions of CMAKE.

Comment: If I remember correctly for me it was enough to just create a new build - maybe Creator saved some values in an incompatible way

Comment: My daily vote limit is reached. Tomorrow I'll give you a plus 1 for responding. If I remember :-). I tried deleting the build folder a couple of times. Just now I tried creating a new build in Creator 4.8.1. That didn't do it in my case. I could have sworn that it worked at one point. Now I'm not so sure.

Comment: I'm thinking it may have something to do with sharing configuration with Creator 4.3.1. Like you say - some incompatibility between the two versions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the technical reason but for me creating a new build-folder solved the problem.

Possibly a CMake or Qt-Creator update introduced some new elements in the environment in an incompatible way..

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I was able to resolve a similar issue by resetting the compilers for each of my build and run configurations under **Preferences > Build & Run > Kits** in Qt Creator.

These had been set to *<No compiler>* for some reason, probably related to careless tracking of various CMake files while passing the project back and forth between different architectures.